# Notification manager for Windows 10 to prevent missed notifications and view history

Tags: windows, windows-10, notification

I'm looking for software that improves upon the default notification system built into Windows such that if any notifications come up when I'm not there to see them or just paying attention to something else and don't see them, it'd help with not missing them.

I'm thinking something which indicates that notifications were missed which doesn’t go away until you acknowledge that fact and which allows the ability to view missed notifications.

The use case is that when I get an instant messenger notification, if I’m not there to see it, it won’t be up when I get back to the computer.  I have changed my notification persistence setting to something like 5 min before they disappear to help with this, but that has multiple drawbacks / shortcomings.

Free or paid are both fine.

Comment: I thought there might be a way within the OS but apparently not: https://superuser.com/questions/947947/view-past-notifications-in-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

Try [Notification Logger](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/notification-logger/9mzf9dmhnh3p) for Windows 10. I'm the author of this app )

Comment: Looks very promising. I'm finding out if it has permissions to access the network or not (I know it just lists userNotificationListener but wasn't sure if all apps have implied internet access). If not I'll plan to buy it since I don't need to be concerned about trust.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Growl](http://growl.info/) It has an icon that stays in the tray and has a badge to show notifications. As its always visible, you can always see if there is a missed notification. We have integrated this into our software so not sure if this completely what you are after.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately it's for OS X not for Windows

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong link.  I use it on OS X but my colleague uses it on windows:  http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/